# MacBook Air 10.15.2 Shuts Down on Startup, falsely indicating 0% battery

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, catalina, power

I have a MacBook Air, with Catalina 10.15.2. When I start it up unplugged, with a full battery, most of the time it starts up and then immediately shuts down. When I hit the power button again, it shows the red power indicator with 0%. I plug it in and it launches just fine.

I brought it into the local Best Buy and they ran hardware diagnostics and said everything looks fine.

How can I get it working without cord ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the battery in your laptop is shot. It might say it's fully charged, but the internals are no longer sufficiently capable of holding a charge or delivering enough of a consistent supply of electricity to safely run the laptop (to be clear, by "safely", I mean "without it losing power and shutting down", not "without causing harm to you and your loved ones").

I suspect it won't be long before the battery stops saying it's fully charged, and starts displaying an X through the charge level icon.

What you describe is exactly what happened to my old MacBook a few years ago.

Answer (score 0):

1. Perform an [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)
2. If an SMC reset doesn't resolve the issue, I would recommend taking it to the Apple store. BestBuy Geeksquad aren't trained on Apple hardware (they are untrained in general) aren't authorized Apple repair centers.

You can check to see if your hardware is still under warranty [here](https://checkcoverage.apple.com/). Apple should still offer you in store support to diagnose the issue. If a hardware fault is found, it would be covered under the warranty. If you're out of warrant, you'll have to pay for the repair out of pocket.